# Can I quickly revert to an older version of my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I found a bug in my chrome extension soon after I published. Can I revert to the stable version and avoid users getting the buggy version that just got published?

Comment: You will need to publish a new version with the old code.

Comment: Thanks @DanielHerr So strange that it asks you to do that and the manifest has to have a version number greater than the last :(

Comment: it will again take some time to reflect right?

Comment: This answer is relatively old. This comment is relatively new and 'You will need to publish a new version with the old code' is still valid.

Answer (score 4):

The Chrome Web Store doesn't offer rollbacks, you will have to increase the version number and publish the old version again as if it were a new one.

On Mozilla Addons, you can just click the "Delete/disable" button on the latest version on the *Manage Status & Versions* page:

[image: Listed version]